# Se detiene App cuando ingreso a mi actividad donde tengo un listview

Tags: java, android

El ***LogCat*** me arroja este error:

```
03-06 14:09:42.618 1933-1933/com.example.usuario.app.myroodent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.usuario.app.myroodent, PID: 1933
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type java.sql.Timestamp, got java.util.Date
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzg$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:690)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzg$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:658)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzg.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:487)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:226)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:81)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:175)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:97)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:156)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:78)
    at com.example.usuario.app.myroodent.EspeciesActivity$1.onEvent(EspeciesActivity.java:57)
    at com.example.usuario.app.myroodent.EspeciesActivity$1.onEvent(EspeciesActivity.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:1834)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzh.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:28)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzi.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Esta es mi actividad ***EspeciesActivity*** donde me genera el error:

```
public class EspeciesActivity extends RegistrosActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "FireLog";
    private RecyclerView mMainList;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private AvistAdapter avistAdapter;
    private List<ReporteEspecie> reportesEspecies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_especies);

        reportesEspecies = new ArrayList<>();
        avistAdapter = new AvistAdapter(reportesEspecies);

        mMainList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        mMainList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mMainList.setAdapter(avistAdapter);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mFirestore.collection("reportes").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots,FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(e !=null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
                }
                for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                    if(doc.getType()== DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                        ReporteEspecie reporteEspecie = doc.getDocument().toObject(ReporteEspecie.class);
                        reportesEspecies.add(reporteEspecie);

                        avistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Agrego Activity ***ReporteEspecie.java***

```
public class ReporteEspecie {

    String email,direccion,especie,nombre;
    Timestamp fechaYhora;

    public ReporteEspecie(){

    }

    public ReporteEspecie(String email, String direccion, String especie, String nombre, Timestamp fechaYhora) {
        this.email = email;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.especie = especie;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaYhora = fechaYhora;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getEspecie() {
        return especie;
    }

    public void setEspecie(String especie) {
        this.especie = especie;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Timestamp getFechaYhora() {

        return fechaYhora;
    }

    public void setFechaYhora(Timestamp fechaYhora) {

        this.fechaYhora = fechaYhora;
    }

}
```

Comment: El codigo se debe subir como codigo, no como imagen

Comment: El error esta en que tenes dos tipos de datos diferentes, lo dice el logcat  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type java.sql.Timestamp, got java.util.Date

Comment: Subi como esta echa la clase ReporteEspecie porfavor, necesito ver sus atributos mas que nada

Comment: @LcsGrz disculpa el desorden amigo ahi subi mi activity completa Gracias de antemano si me puedes colaborar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno la solucion creeria que esta aca, tal como dice el logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type java.sql.Timestamp, got java.util.Date
```

Y el error esta en la linea

```
at com.example.usuario.app.myroodent.EspeciesActivity$1.onEvent(EspeciesActivity.java:57)
```

Por lo tanto lo que esta sucediendo es que estas recibiendo un tipo DATE y estas queriendolo inserertar en un campo TIMESTAMP

Hay dos soluciones,la primera es que crees tu propio dezerializador, pero no creo que sea conveniente, y la segunda es que cambies el atributo de tu clase **ReporteEspecie** a tipo DATE, quedando tu clase de la siguiente manera

```
public class ReporteEspecie {

    String email,direccion,especie,nombre;
    Date fechaYhora;

    public ReporteEspecie(){

    }

    public ReporteEspecie(String email, String direccion, String especie, String nombre, Date fechaYhora) {
        this.email = email;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.especie = especie;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaYhora = fechaYhora;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getEspecie() {
        return especie;
    }

    public void setEspecie(String especie) {
        this.especie = especie;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Date getFechaYhora() {

        return fechaYhora;
    }

    public void setFechaYhora(Date fechaYhora) {

        this.fechaYhora = fechaYhora;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo me sirvió mucho tu recomendación solo cambie Timestamp por Date y me funcionó perfecto solo que aun me falta que mi listview se vea correctamente

Comment: No se si tengas idea de como lograrlo pero necesito q mi listview se vea asi https://xd.adobe.com/view/8a9f4f8e-50c6-4022-576a-9e73184fdcec-fcae/
Por ahora se esta visualizando de esta manera  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hcLkMD6mlk854T38JkzsXs_iVGOdYlW_

Comment: Recorda que si la respuesta te fue util, votarla como positivo y marcarla como respuesta correcta. ´Para el caso del listView, deberas crear un adapter y asignarle el componente que quieres que se visualize, para hacer el componente te recomiendo ConstraintLayout